# Any good free full version software similar to "Hide All IP"?

Tags: networking, game-development, proxy, vpn, firewall

I like to play games online with gameranger. The problem is that I get this nasty message :
[image]

[image]

Port forwarding at my local machine does not seem to work. It seems I will have to contact ISP which is a pain. I found that using `HideAllIp` I no longer get this message and I am able to connect with everyone. It did not limit my bandwith either. But unfortunately it's a paid software. Any free alternatives?
 I tried `HotspotShield` but it did not work.

Comment: Take a look at [psiphon](https://www.psiphon.ca/) or tor the latter is a bit slower..

Comment: @xavier_fakerat while tor is only for surfing internet, phisphon seems to be similar to hotspotshield. It did not resolve NAT issue that i  am facing. The only software that worked was hideallip

Comment: Is UPnP enabled?